# Problem with parsing negative numbers in Java

Tags: java, parsing, split

I have string that I have parsed and I can split up all of the necessary items.  I can take in the following values:
"|You're in a large dark room| false 1 -1 -1 2 ", 
                "|You're in a dark large room| false -1 0 -1 -1 ",
                "|You're in a large room, very dark| false 0 0 3 0 ",
                "|You're in a dark room, very small| true 0 0 0 0 "
and I can get the description, true/false value, and the numbers to all separate.  However, when I try to parse the numbers into an integer value, I get a number exception error.

I had originally tried using an integer, roomValue, and a Scanner, roomString, to getNextInt() into the roomValue.  That failed horribly.  The code below splits everything up but once I try to assign the integer value of my string array, I get the error.

```
        description = fullDesc.substring(1, fullDesc.indexOf("| "));
        gameRooms[roomNumber] = new Room(description);
        fullDesc = fullDesc.substring(fullDesc.indexOf("| ") + 2);

        if (fullDesc.contains("true")) 
            gameRooms[roomNumber].putGrail();
        fullDesc = fullDesc.substring(fullDesc.indexOf(" "));       
        String[] roomString = fullDesc.split(" ");
        Integer[] adjRoomNum = new Integer[roomString.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < roomString.length; i++) {
            //adjRoomNum[i] = Integer.parseInt(roomString[i]);
            //System.out.println(adjRoomNum[i]);
            System.out.println((roomString[i]));
        }

        /*
        roomValue = roomString.nextInt();
        if ((roomValue) >= 0)
            gameRooms[roomNumber].setAdjacent(0, gameRooms[Integer.valueOf(roomValue)]);
        else if ((roomValue) == -1)
            gameRooms[roomNumber].setAdjacent(0, null);
        roomString  
        roomValue = roomString.nextInt();
        if ((roomValue) >= 0)
            gameRooms[roomNumber].setAdjacent(1, gameRooms[Integer.valueOf(roomValue)]);
        else if ((roomValue) == -1)
            gameRooms[roomNumber].setAdjacent(1, null);
        roomValue = roomString.nextInt();
        if ((roomValue) >= 0)
            gameRooms[roomNumber].setAdjacent(2, gameRooms[Integer.valueOf(roomValue)]);
        else if ((roomValue) == -1)
            gameRooms[roomNumber].setAdjacent(2, null);
        roomValue = roomString.nextInt();
        if ((roomValue) >= 0)
            gameRooms[roomNumber].setAdjacent(3, gameRooms[Integer.valueOf(roomValue)]);
        else if ((roomValue) == -1)
            gameRooms[roomNumber].setAdjacent(3, null);
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at Controller.buildRoom(Controller.java:30)
    at Game.main(Game.java:67)
```

The output of the string is

```
1
-1
-1
2

-1
0
-1
-1

0
0
3
0

0
0
0
0
```

What I want is

```
1
-1
-1
2
-1
0
-1
-1
0
0
3
0
0
0
0
0
```

I see that there is white space that gets read into the first value of the string array and that throws the parsing into a number format exception.  I tried to remove the white space but I haven't been successful.

Comment: when asking about code taking an input, supposed to produce an output, but instead generating an error, you need to post the actual code, the actual expected output, and the actual error. We don't even know if you're asking about a compilation error or a runtime error, what the error is, if it's caued by the code you posted, or by the commented code, or by something else.

Comment: Thank you very much @JBNizet.  I get ansy when I try and ask a question and forget that my question is not clear.  I will try and remember this.

Answer (score 0):

If your roomString array contains the strings like "1" or "-1" then you can do the below part

```
for (int i = 0; i < roomString.length; i++) {
  if(roomString[i].charAt(0) == '-'){
    roomString[i] = roomString[i].substring(1);
    adjRoomNum[i] = Integer.parseInt(roomString[i]) * (-1);
  }else{
    adjRoomNum[i] = Integer.parseInt(roomString[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have white space between the minus and the first number hance,
once you doing the split - String[] roomString = fullDesc.split(" ");
the first string is empty string
so it fails on parsing
you should avoid it or by remove it or by split it

```
if(fullDesc.startWith("")) {
//substring
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Integer.parseInt()** method **will** accept string representations of signed (negative) integer values like **"-1024"** and convert that string to **int**. As a matter of fact, it will also accept something like **"+1024"**. What it **won't convert** is a Null, Null String (""), or any numerical string which contains one or more alpha characters including the whitespace. The error message you display indicates that an attempt was made to pass a Null String (**""**) through the **Integer.parseInt()** method.

IMHO it's a good idea to validate the string before carrying out the conversion so as to eliminate the worry of generating an exception or, at the very least try to catch the exception and deal with it.

**Validating a Numerical String using the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method:**

In this example the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method is used along with a [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx) to validate the fact that the string contained within **roomString[i]** array element is indeed a string representation of a signed or unsigned integer numerical value. If it's not then an error message is displayed to console and processing continues with the next array element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < roomString.length; i++) {
    // Trim off an possible leading or trailing whitespaces.
    roomString[i] = roomString[i].trim();
    if (!roomString[i].matches("\\+?\\d+|\\-?\\d+")) {
        System.err.println("The value " + roomString[i] + " located at " + 
                           "index " + i + " can not be converted to Integer!");
        continue;  // continue processing the remaining array.
    }
    adjRoomNum[i] = Integer.parseInt(roomString[i]);
    System.out.println(adjRoomNum[i]);
    //System.out.println((roomString[i]));
}
```

The RegEx used (`"\\+?\\d+|\\-?\\d+"`) means this:

- `\\+?\\d+` If the string starts with a literal **+** character or not
  and then is followed by one or more digits from 0 to 9
- `|` OR
- `\\-?\\d+"` If the string starts with a literal **-** character or
  not and then is followed by one or more digits from 0 to 9.

You most likely may not need the portion: `\\+?\\d+|` and can leave it out of the expression.

**Catching the NumberFormatException:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < roomString.length; i++) {
    // Trim off an possible leading or trailing whitespaces.
    roomString[i] = roomString[i].trim(); 
    try {
        adjRoomNum[i] = Integer.parseInt(roomString[i]);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.err.println("The value " + roomString[i] + " located at " + 
                           "index " + i + " can not be converted to Integer!");
        continue;  // continue processing the remaining array.
    }

    System.out.println(adjRoomNum[i]);
    //System.out.println((roomString[i]));
}
```

**How did you get the Null String ("") to start with?**

When parsing a string based on white-spaces especial if a string from User Input there is always the possibility that a double-space was supplied *somewhere* or, in your case a single leading whitespace (more on this later). To handle this dilemma always trim the string with the [String#trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) method to remove leading and trailing white-spaces **before** splitting that string.

**Parsing And Splitting Your Particular Strings:**

In general, your parsing works fine but you'll notice that when this code line is run:

```
fullDesc = fullDesc.substring(fullDesc.indexOf(" "));
```

the **fullDesc** variable will hold the string's integer values with a leading and trailing white-space, for example: `" 1 -1 -1 2 "`. You don't want this since this would split into: `"", "1", "-1", "-1", "2"`. Your **roomString** array would hold one Null String element because of the leading white-space and the **Integer.parseInt()** method will not handle those therefore throwing a **NumberFormatException**. The solution is simple, just add **1** to the substring index or add the **trim()** method to the end of the code line. Modify the code line above to this:

```
fullDesc = fullDesc.substring(fullDesc.indexOf(" ") + 1);

                          O R

// Covers almost all the 'just in case' situations.
fullDesc = fullDesc.substring(fullDesc.indexOf(" ")).trim();
```

This however doesn't cover the possible situation of double-spacing between values when you want to split the string, for example:

```
    "1  -1 -1  2"
```

Here we have a double space between 1 and -1 and yet again between -1 and 2. When this string is split based on a single white-space (`String[] roomString = "1  -1 -1  2".split(" ");`) you will end up with six array elements, two of which will be Null Strings (`"1", "", "-1", "-1", "", "2"`) and again, the **Integer.parseInt()** method would end up throwing a **NumberFormatException** when a Null String is encountered.

The solution, don't use `" "` within your split method. Use `"\\s+"` instead. This small regular expression tells the split() method to split the string on ***one or more*** white-spaces.

When dealing with String digits and you want to parse them using **Integer.parseInt()**, **Double.parseDouble()**, or whatever a white-space within the numerical string cause havoc regardless of the delimiter you are using. Take this example of a comma (,) delimited numerical string that a User entered into a Console application:

```
"1, 2, 3,4,5 ,6 ,7,8 , 9 , 10"
```

There are four different delimited situations here:

```
1) 1, 2
2) 3,4
3) 5 ,6
4) , 9 ,
```

If you were to split this string say with:

```
String[] values = "1, 2, 3,4,5 ,6 ,7,8 , 9 , 10".split(",");
```

Your values array would hold:

```
["1", " 2", " 3", "4", "5 ", "6 ", "7", "8 ", " 9 ", " 10"]
```

All the array elements which contain a white-space in them will cause a **NumberFormatException** when you try to parse these elements through the **Integer.parseInt()** method. The solution, to cover all the bases perhaps split it like this:

```
String[] values = "1, 2, 3,4,5 ,6 ,7,8 , 9 , 10".split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}");
```

What does this regular expression mean: `"\\s{0,},\\s{0,}"`? Split on a comma even if there are 0 or more white-spaces before or after that comma.

Your code could possibly look like this:

```
String[] gameStrings = {
    "|You're in a large dark room| false 1 -1 -1 2 ",
    "|You're in a dark large room| false -1 0 -1 -1 ",
    "|You're in a large room, very dark| false 0 0 3 0 ",
    "|You're in a dark room, very small| true 0 0 0 0 "
};

for (int s = 0; s < gameStrings.length; s++) {
    String fullDesc = gameStrings[s];
    String description = fullDesc.substring(1, fullDesc.indexOf("| "));
    gameRooms[roomNumber] = new Room(description);
    fullDesc = fullDesc.substring(fullDesc.indexOf("| ") + 2);

    if (fullDesc.contains("true")) {
        gameRooms[roomNumber].putGrail();
    }
    fullDesc = fullDesc.substring(fullDesc.indexOf(" ")).trim();
    String[] roomString = fullDesc.split("\\s+");
    Integer[] adjRoomNum = new Integer[roomString.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < roomString.length; i++) {
        if (!roomString[i].trim().matches("\\+?\\d+|\\-?\\d+")) {
            System.err.println("The value " + roomString[i] + " located at "
                    + "index " + i + " can not be converted to Integer!");
            continue; // Continue processing array elements.
        }
        adjRoomNum[i] = Integer.parseInt(roomString[i]);
        System.out.println(adjRoomNum[i]);
    }
}
```